# could not find a non-generic method 'Delete' that has parameters

Tags: asp.net

That's a string returned from .net when using a Gridview control bound to an ObjectDataSource. The ObjectDataSource is bound to a tableAdapter in a .net DataSet.

The dataset has a table adapter that is auto generated and has created an update, insert, select and delete stored proc in my database.

The grid is now using this source and should allow insert, updates and deletes.

Insert and updates are working but the delete specifically gives the error

ObjectDataSource 'odsCustomerAliases' could not find a non-generic method 'Delete' that has parameters: CustomerAlias, original_CustomerAlias.

Whilst I can read the error I have tried a number of things and cannot get this to work. I can't really see how it's expecting a parameter 'original_CustomerAlias'

I can confirm this parameter does not exist in the proc.

Here are some code snippets which seem to be correct.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsCustomerAliases" runat="server" DeleteMethod="Delete"
                InsertMethod="Insert" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetData"
                TypeName="SLRDataAccess.dsTableAdapters.CustomerAliasesTableAdapter" UpdateMethod="Update">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerAlias" Type="String" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="original_CustomerAlias" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerAlias" Type="String" />
                </UpdateParameters>
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:SessionParameter Name="CustomerID" SessionField="CustomerID" Type="Int32" />
                </SelectParameters>
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerAlias" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerID" Type="Int32" />
                </InsertParameters>
            </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

The section from the auto generated dataset.

```
<DeleteCommand>
              <DbCommand CommandType="StoredProcedure" ModifiedByUser="False">
                <CommandText>dbo.usp_DeleteCustomerAlias</CommandText>
                <Parameters>
                  <Parameter AllowDbNull="True" AutogeneratedName="" DataSourceName="" DbType="Int32" Direction="ReturnValue" ParameterName="@RETURN_VALUE" Precision="10" ProviderType="Int" Scale="0" Size="4" SourceColumnNullMapping="False" SourceVersion="Current">
                  </Parameter>
                  <Parameter AllowDbNull="True" AutogeneratedName="" DataSourceName="" DbType="AnsiString" Direction="Input" ParameterName="@CustomerAlias" Precision="0" ProviderType="VarChar" Scale="0" Size="100" SourceColumn="CustomerAlias" SourceColumnNullMapping="False" SourceVersion="Current">
                  </Parameter>
                </Parameters>
              </DbCommand>
            </DeleteCommand>
```

The final code snippet from the designer which I imagine is not actually relevant but...

```
<Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(),  _
     Global.System.ComponentModel.Design.HelpKeywordAttribute("vs.data.TableAdapter"),  _
     Global.System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(Global.System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Delete, true)>  _
    Public Overloads Overridable Function Delete(ByVal CustomerAlias As String) As Integer
        If (CustomerAlias Is Nothing) Then
            Me.Adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters(1).Value = Global.System.DBNull.Value
        Else
            Me.Adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters(1).Value = CType(CustomerAlias,String)
        End If
        Dim previousConnectionState As Global.System.Data.ConnectionState = Me.Adapter.DeleteCommand.Connection.State
        If ((Me.Adapter.DeleteCommand.Connection.State And Global.System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)  _
                    <> Global.System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) Then
            Me.Adapter.DeleteCommand.Connection.Open
        End If
        Try 
            Dim returnValue As Integer = Me.Adapter.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery
            Return returnValue
        Finally
            If (previousConnectionState = Global.System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed) Then
                Me.Adapter.DeleteCommand.Connection.Close
            End If
        End Try
    End Function
```

Comment: how many argument you have found objectdatasource deleting event?

Comment: have you change OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" to OldValuesParameterFormatString="{0}"

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with attribute OldValuesParameterFormatString - that forces method to accept 2 arguments. Just remove it attribute at all.

Comment: Then add this fictive to Delete as expected

Comment: I did add the expected parameter to the stored proc but that didn't make any difference. But the markup shows the delete statement doesn't expect this parameter anyway, not in the dataset designer or on the page.

Lot's of people are having this error and changing the oldvaluesparameterformatstring shouldn't really be necessary as the object should be maintaining an old and new anyway.  Maybe I should of changed the delete parameter to the original_ version and tried that but i've just coded my own instead and done away with the hit and miss auto generated classes.

Answer (score 0):

The same error occurred with me and I solved it by just changing the value of the OldValuesParameterFormatString attribute from "original_{0}" to just "{0}".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure your parameter names match in all places.
If you see this error: ObjectDataSource could not find a non-generic method that has parameters. Odds are yours id's do not match up in all places.

Here's an example, Notice the id 'ScheduleId' used in the grid, ods paramters and data access function

```
<asp:GridView ID="uxgvSchedule" DataKeyNames="ScheduleId" ... 

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lblDeleteSchedule" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"  CommandArgument="<%# CType(Container, GridViewRow).RowIndex %>" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

</asp:GridView>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsSchedule" DeleteMethod="DeleteSchedule" OnDeleting="odsSchedule_Deleting" ... />

<DeleteParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="ScheduleId" Type="Int32" />
</DeleteParameters>

Protected Sub uxgvSchedule_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles uxgvSchedule.RowCommand
Try
    Dim tempInt As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(e.CommandArgument, tempInt) Then
        Dim row As GridViewRow = uxgvSchedule.Rows(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument))
        Dim rowkey As DataKey = uxgvSchedule.DataKeys(row.RowIndex)
        uxlblScheduleId.Text = rowkey.Value
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
End Sub

Protected Sub odsSchedule_Deleting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs) Handles odsSchedule.Deleting
    ************VERY COMMON CAUSE - FIX ******************
    'e.InputParameters("ScheduleId") = uxlblScheduleId.Text

    '2nd time i ran into this problem the error was indicating more 
    'than one parameter or a completely different set of parameters, 
    'so I would nearly do this instead from now on in this function
    e.InputParameters.Clear()
    e.InputParameters.Add("ScheduleId", uxlblScheduleId.Text)
End Sub

Public Function DeleteSchedule(ByVal ScheduleId As Integer) As Integer
    Dim rowsAffected As Integer = 0
    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("DeleteSchedule", con)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ScheduleId", SqlDbType.Int))
    cmd.Parameters("@ScheduleId").Value = ScheduleId

    Try
        con.Open()
        rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch sqlex As SqlException
    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
    Return rowsAffected
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the `OldValuesParameterFormatString` in the `ObjectDataSource' tag with the same name of`DeleteParameters`.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
    DeleteMethod="DeleteBook" SelectMethod="LoadAllBooks" **OldValuesParameterFormatString="ISBN"** 
    TypeName="BusinessLayer.clsBusiness">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ISBN" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```