# ASP.Net MySql non-generic method 'UpdateQuery'

Tags: mysql, asp.net, visual-studio

I am running into an issue with a GridView and DataSet where the update command seems to be trying add too many parameters to the SQL query. I have scoured Google and StackOverflow for potential fixes but seem to be turning up empty handed.

Everything works perfect until I hit the Update link on the GridView after making necessary edits. When I press the Update button I am faced with the following error:

```
ObjectDataSource 'ObjectDataSource1' could not find a non-generic method 'Update' that has parameters: p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, siteID, serialNumber, installDate, testDate, lastAlarmDate, alarmState, sensorType, sensorLocation, squelched, emsNotified, original_sensorID.
```

I have verified the Update statement generated by the DataSet and it reflects as follows:

```
UPDATE sensors SET siteID = @p1, serialNumber = @p2, installDate = @p3, testDate = @p4, lastAlarmDate = @p5, alarmState = @p6, sensorType = @p7, sensorLocation = @p8, squelched = @p9, emsNotified = @p10 WHERE (sensorID = @p11)
```

It appears there is extra data being appended to the end of the update string and I cannot find where it is appending these additional variables from. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

GridView Markup

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="sensorID" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="sensorID" HeaderText="sensorID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="sensorID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="siteID" HeaderText="siteID" SortExpression="siteID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="serialNumber" HeaderText="serialNumber" SortExpression="serialNumber" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="installDate" HeaderText="installDate" SortExpression="installDate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="testDate" HeaderText="testDate" SortExpression="testDate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="lastAlarmDate" HeaderText="lastAlarmDate" SortExpression="lastAlarmDate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="alarmState" HeaderText="alarmState" SortExpression="alarmState" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="sensorType" HeaderText="sensorType" SortExpression="sensorType" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="sensorLocation" HeaderText="sensorLocation" SortExpression="sensorLocation" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="squelched" HeaderText="squelched" SortExpression="squelched" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="emsNotified" HeaderText="emsNotified" SortExpression="emsNotified" />
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

ObjectDataSource Markup

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" DeleteMethod="Delete" InsertMethod="Insert" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="DataSetTableAdapters.sitesTableAdapter" UpdateMethod="Update" OnSelecting="ObjectDataSource1_Selecting">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="p1" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="p1" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="p2" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="p1" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="p2" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="p3" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Edit: Verbiage.
Edit 2: Markup.
Edit 3: Additional markup.

Comment: Can we see your `ObjectDataSource` markup and code behind? Usually this error originated from wrong `TypeName`, wrong method arguments set by `DataObjectMethodType.Update` attribute or not setting `ConflictDetection="OverwriteChanges"`.

Comment: The code behind is the nativly generated GridView code. I am not sure how to get you this code as I was always taught to leave it alone. However, I have provided the markup per your request.

Comment: What I see is the markup of `GridView`, can you provide markup of `ObjectDataSource1` pointed by `DataSourceID` attribute (I think it should be `asp:ObjectDataSource` indeed)?

Comment: Gotcha, I misread your original commend before. I have added the requested markup code to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

According to the SQL query statement to update data source, it has 11 parameters (10 `SET` parameters and 1 `WHERE` clause parameter):

```
UPDATE sensors SET siteID = @p1, serialNumber = @p2, installDate = @p3, 
                   testDate = @p4, lastAlarmDate = @p5, alarmState = @p6, 
                   sensorType = @p7, sensorLocation = @p8, squelched = @p9, emsNotified = @p10 
               WHERE (sensorID = @p11)
```

But in `UpdateParameters` you're only declared 3 parameters, and you should know that `ObjectDataSource` requires amount of CRUD parameters matched exactly with declared parameters in query statement above (also with same parameter names), hence you need to adjust number of query parameters like this:

```
<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="p1" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="p2" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="p3" Type="DateTime" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="p4" Type="DateTime" />
    <%-- other required parameters --%>
    <asp:Parameter Name="p11" Type="Int32" />
</UpdateParameters>
```

Second, I found that the exception expects `original_sensorID` which reflects usage of attribute `OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"`. Try replace old values parameter format string as given below, or just remove that attribute:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
                      OldValuesParameterFormatString="{0}" ...>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

**Side note:**

Make sure that this attribute `TypeName="DataSetTableAdapters.sitesTableAdapter"` set to proper fully-qualified type name of the data source.

Additional references:

[GridView with ObjectDataSource Example: Insert, Edit, Update](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/06/gridview-objectdatasource-insert-update.html)

[could not find a non-generic method 'Delete' that has parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232869/could-not-find-a-non-generic-method-delete-that-has-parameters)

[ObjectDataSource could not find a non-generic method that has parameters when using update and delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125126/objectdatasource-could-not-find-a-non-generic-method-that-has-parameters-when-us?rq=1)

Comment: I will need to verify the missing parameters as you have identified. The other recommendations yielded the same results when changed. I'll make necessary adjustments and report back.